# Assign JSON object value to variable

Tags: json, angularjs, variable-assignment

I'm trying to extract a certain name/value pair from a JSON object & assign it to a variable.

A sample of my object

```
{"new":[{"id":"185","title":"new time","slug":"new-time","time":"1363641168","text":"all done","deletetime":null}]
```

I'm trying to assign the time to a timestamp variable for later use in my AngularJS app. Anyway that I attempt, it returns as *undefined*.

```
$scope.news = data.new["time"];
```

What is the correct way to access the value of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"new" is an array, so the first item's time prop is:

```
data.new[0].time
```

Comment: Great! That seems like such an obvious answer. I was able to assign it to a variable without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

new is a keyword in JavaScript, so you won't be able to use it in your property access notation.  Consider renaming the new element in your data to be 'newItems' or something.

Comment: I didn't even think about that. It doesn't seem to cause a problem though. Could that be because it exists within an object that it doesn't cause an issue?

Comment: I went ahead and changed from the _new_ keyword.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem in this case actually. But its a good thing to remember.